# Metric on natural numbers united with infinity

Tags: metric-spaces, natural-numbers

can anyone give me an example for the following metric $d$?

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{N}_+ \cup \{ \infty \}$ and $d$ be a metric such that all points $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ are isolated w.r.t. $d$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d(n,\infty) = 0$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take your favourite convergent sequence with no repeated terms.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand this answer. In fact, I have not studied mathematics.

Comment: @mathie314: Do you understand what $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(n,\infty)=0$$ means, rigorously?

Comment: $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that $\forall n\geq n_0:~d(n,\infty) <\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: A rough idea, here, is to treat each $n$ like $\frac1n.$ What can we treat $\infty$ like to get the desired property?

Comment: Okay, I see that $d(x,y) = \frac1x - \frac1y$ does the job for the second condition. But I am somehow confused about this isolated stuff.

Comment: Of course, I meant $d(x,y) = \left| \frac1x - \frac1y\right|$.

Comment: True, so long as we stipulate that $\frac1\infty=0.$  All points in $\Bbb N_+$ are isolated under this metric because  for any $n\in\Bbb N_+,$ there us some $\delta>0$ such that if $x\in\Omega$ and $d(n,x)<\delta,$ then $x=n.$ This $\delta$ will depend on $n,$ but it exists.

Answer (score 0):

All the points $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ are isolated because there exists open sets $\mathcal{O}_{\epsilon}=\{y\in\Omega|d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ around $x$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\mathcal{O}_{\epsilon}=\{x\}$.

Comment: Where is $y$ coming from? And are you implying that all points $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$ are isolated w.r.t. any possible metric?

Comment: @mathie314: I will edit.

Comment: Okay, but still I wonder whether this holds for any metric.

Comment: @mathie314: It hold for your metric above. The question was: find a metric for which all $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ are isolated.

Comment: Okay, but then you just cited the definition of isolated points. Anyways, I got it now.

Comment: @mathie314: Yes, the definition, I hope...